# Python: convert a dot separated hex values to string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, hex, data-conversion

In this post: [Print a string as hex bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214801/python-print-a-string-as-hex-bytes) I learned how to print as string into an "array" of hex bytes now I need something the other way around:

So for example the input would be: `73.69.67.6e.61.74.75.72.65` and the output would be a string.

Comment: The output would be **what** string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without [`binascii`](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html):

```
>>> a="73.69.67.6e.61.74.75.72.65"  
>>> "".join(chr(int(e, 16)) for e in a.split('.'))  
'signature'  
>>>
```

or better:

```
>>> a="73.69.67.6e.61.74.75.72.65"  
>>> "".join(e.decode('hex') for e in a.split('.'))
```

PS: works with unicode:

```
>>> a='.'.join(x.encode('hex') for x in 'Hellö Wörld!')
>>> a
'48.65.6c.6c.94.20.57.94.72.6c.64.21'
>>> print "".join(e.decode('hex') for e in a.split('.'))
Hellö Wörld!
>>>
```

**EDIT:**

No need for a generator expression here (thx to  thg435):

```
a.replace('.', '').decode('hex')
```

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean, but I added an example with a string containing a german umlaut (`ö`).

Comment: I was thinking you are saying about UTF8 that has more bytes for a character.

Comment: @thg435 mmmh... that was too obvious... not seeing the wood for the trees... :-)

Answer (score 3):

you can use the built in [`binascii`](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html) module. Do note however that this function will only work on ASCII encoded characters.

```
binascii.unhexlify(hexstr)
```

Your input string will need to be dotless however, but that is quite easy with a simple

```
string = string.replace('.','')
```

another (arguably safer) method would be to use base64 in the following way:

```
import base64
encoded = base64.b16encode(b'data to be encoded')
print (encoded)
data = base64.b16decode(encoded)
print (data)
```

or in your example:

```
data = base64.b16decode(b"7369676e6174757265", True)
print (data.decode("utf-8"))
```

The string can be sanitised before input into the `b16decode` method.
Note that I am using python 3.2 and you may not necessarily need the `b` out the front of the string to denote bytes.

Example was [found here](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html#module-base64)

Answer (score 1):

Use [string split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to get a list of strings, then [base 16 for decoding](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) the bytes.

```
>>> inp="73.69.67.6e.61.74.75.72.65"
>>> ''.join((chr(int(i,16)) for i in inp.split('.')))
'signature'
>>>
```