# Unable to print hex value of data receive from serial port

Tags: python-2.7, serial-port, hex, type-conversion

I need print hex value of '?' this character

currently, my script returns wierd characters such as '?' or '£☻
§"

I want to read them as proper hex value.

```
if choice == 8:
   incoming =ser.readline()     
   print incoming
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this post: [Print a string as hex bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214801/print-a-string-as-hex-bytes)

You ultimately need to encode each character as it's raw hex byte using `c.encode('hex')` where `c` is a character in your string.