# Convert a string into an hexadecimal

Tags: python, string, int, hex

I have a string file, but the strings in it represent hexadecimal values. For example, I have this kind of string in my file:

```
1091    A3B7    56FF    ...
```

And I don't want to use them as string, but as hexadecimal values; and then convert the hexadecimal into an int.

For example:

`1091(in string)---> 1091(in hexa)---> 4241   # The int value of 1091 in hexa`

So I looked on the Internet. I tried a lot of different methods such as:

1. *[Print a string as hex bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214801/print-a-string-as-hex-bytes)*
2. *[Convert hex string to int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)*

But nothing fit exactly with what I need, or simply does not work.

This is a part of my code:

```
t = False
i = 0
while t != True and h != True or i <=100: # My way to look each string of my file
    file = row[1]
    read_byte = file[i]

    if read_byte == 'V': #V is the letter in my file which says that it s the data that I want then there is 2 kinds of channel 01 and 02 that interest me

        i=i+1
        a=i+2
        read_bytechannel = file[i:a]  #read 2 strings because the channel can be '01' or '02'

        if read_bytechannel == '01':
            print(read_bytechannel)
            i=i+1
            a=i+4
            read_bytetemp = file[i:a] # Reading 4 strings because the value is the int value of the two hexa.
            realintvalue= # (?????????convert the read_bytetemp string value into an hexa value, then into an int from the hexa)

            tempfinal = realintvalue/100 # I have to divide by 100 the int value to get the real temperature
            t = True # This condition just tell me that I already know the temporary

    i = i+1
```

And this is the kind of file I want to read:

```
@
I01010100B00725030178
V01109103
I02020100B00725030148
V0215AA5C
$
@
```

Comment: Your input is not hexadecimal and it does not look like the `1091 A3B7 56FF` you describe at the beginning. What is your real input?

Comment: My initial input are byte from a serial usb, that I put into an sql database, then now I am analysing the datum, so I have to read from the database. But what I showed you at the end of my question, was exactly what I get if I look the file created by the serial read of my script.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your real input and describe the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> int('1091', 16)
4241
```

The second parameter to [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) is the base which to interpret the first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, int with base 16:

```
>>> my_string = "1091 A3B7 56FF"
>>> map(lambda x:int(x,16), my_string.split())
[4241, 41911, 22271]
```

Or you can have both:

```
>>> map(lambda x:[x,int(x,16)], my_string.split())
[['1091', 4241], ['A3B7', 41911], ['56FF', 22271]]
```

If you are not comfortable with `lambda` and `map`, you can use *list comprehension*:

```
>>> [[x,int(x,16)] for x in my_string.split()]
[['1091', 4241], ['A3B7', 41911], ['56FF', 22271]]
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if my strong is only 1091? because I tried you method, and it gives me:
<map object at 0x1006b8b70>
this as an answer and I would like 4241. Thank you again

Comment: @MaxTaylor  if you using python3, apply list, like this `list(map(lambda x:int(x,16), my_string.split()))`