# Converting Python Networking Code To Java

Tags: java, python, sockets, networking

Given the following function definitions in `Python`:

```
class NetworkClient:
    def __init__(self, ip):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
        self.s.connect((str(ip), 7331))

    def readmem(self, address, length):
        if length == 0: raise BaseException, "Why are you giving me no length" #Please don't do this to me
        if not self.ValidMemory().validrange(address, length): return
        if not self.ValidMemory().validaccess(address, length, "read"): return
        self.s.send("\x04") #cmd_readmem
        request = struct.pack(">II", address, address + length)
        self.s.send(request)
        status  = self.s.recv(1)
        if status == "\xbd": #Non-zero memory was found
            response = self.s.recv(length)
        elif status == "\xb0": #All zeroes
            response = "\x00" * length
        else: return #Something went terribly wrong
        return response
```

I now want to do the same in `Java`. As example I want to read the memory at address `0x10000003` with length `0x1` e.g. 1 byte.

So far I wrote the following code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class NetworkClient
{
    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        try (Socket clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.178.35", 7331);
             PrintWriter outputWriter =
                     new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
             BufferedReader inputReader =
                     new BufferedReader(
                                               new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())))
        {
            System.out.println("Connected");

            byte readMemoryCommand = (byte) 4;
            int memoryAddress = 0x10000003;
            int length = 0x1;

            outputWriter.print(readMemoryCommand);
            outputWriter.print(memoryAddress);
            outputWriter.println(memoryAddress + length);

            System.out.println("Receiving");
            System.out.println(inputReader.read());
            System.out.println("Received");
        }
    }

    public static byte[] toByteArray(String letters)
    {
        return letters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    }
}
```

Establishing the connection works but then after sending the data, there is no response. The server does not send anything back and my Java program is stuck on `readLine()`. The output is as follows:

```
Connected
Receiving
```

Replacing `readLine()` with `read()` does not help. Using a `DataOutputStream` with `write` and `writeInt` calls does not work either.

The difficulty I'm having here seems to be to prepare and send the request data correctly. For your information, the Python function [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) produces the following result in an [`interactive Python session`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Interactive_mode):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack(">II", 10000003, 10000004)
b'\x00\x98\x96\x83\x00\x98\x96\x84'
>>>
```

Both integers are converted to hexadecimal and "packed" into a byte array.

The `readmem` command String is converted to an ASCII byte array I believe:

```
>>> print("\x04")
*Box with questionmark in it*
>>> s = "04"
>>> ":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in s)
'30:34'
>>>
```

The latter code for printing the bytes is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12214880/3764804).

So what is wrong with the Java code?

Comment: Actually, python's `"\x04"` is simply a single byte with the value 4. So sending a Java `"04"` is very different.

Comment: @RealSkeptic
So I would rather convert the integer 4 to a byte and send that? In Java I'm doing this: `outputWriter.print((byte) 4);`
However, this still didn't solve the problem

Comment: No, to send bytes in Java, you do not use a `Writer` and you do not use `print`. You use a byte-based `OutputStream` and use `write`. Better yet, use a channel rather than a stream and use a `ByteBuffer`. But you'll have to do some reading of the Java documentation.

Comment: @RealSkeptic
I tried `OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();` and `write()` calls for the 3 arguments and finally a `flush()` but it also didn't work

Comment: You should be using [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) instead of PrintWriter.  Pay close attention to the documentation—the `write` and `writeByte` methods send *one byte,* while `writeInt` sends four bytes.  Similarly, reading should be done with a [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html), specifically the `readByte` and `readFully` methods, rather than BufferedReader.

Comment: @VGR
Thanks a lot, now it is working. Feel free to write an answer to have it accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) instead of PrintWriter. Pay close attention to the documentation—the `write` and `writeByte` methods send *one byte,* while `writeInt` sends four bytes. Similarly, reading should be done with a [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html), specifically the `readByte` and `readFully` methods, rather than BufferedReader.

Writers and Readers deal with text, not bytes.  PrintWriter.print sends an ASCII representation of a number, rather than the byte itself.  BufferedReader (and most Readers) will try to decode the incoming bytes into text, instead of reading the bytes directly.