# printing unicode hex values for strings

Tags: python

I am trying to print unicode characters for strings.
For example, '{' should print as '007B' (with the leading zeroes)

All I can do at the moment is this:

```
binascii.hexlify(unicode("{")) 
'7b'
```

I want to be able to give it a string like "test" and it should print "0074006500730074"

Comment: What's wrong with the `hex` built-in function?

Comment: Unicode function has additional 'encoding' parameter. Try this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print a string as hex bytes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214801/print-a-string-as-hex-bytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string formatting:

```
>>> string = 'test'
>>> ''.join(["{:04x}".format(ord(c)) for c in string])
'0074006500730074'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
character = ...

uni_string = hex(ord(character))[2:].zfill(4)
```

This gets the unicode number, converts to hex, lops off first two characters, then pads the string with zeros up to length 4