# change u‘EW2FB9123456’ to \x45\x57\x32\x46\x42\x39\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36

Tags: python-2.7

I want to change unicode to hex bytes.

How to deal with that?

I use windows 7 and python 2.7.  I have tried
unhexlify() but error occurs: TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found

```
bd_addr = u'EW2FB9123456'
SN_write = b'\x32\xD3\x0D\x02' + unhexlify(bd_addr) + struct.pack("<H", 
 CRC16.calc(b'\x32\xD3\x0D\x02' + unhexlify(bd_addr)))
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [Print a string as hex bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214801/print-a-string-as-hex-bytes)

Comment: Not the same, mine is unicode str