# view bytes as hex values only (do not decode characters)

Tags: python, string, byte

How can I view a bytes array as hex values only?

```
x = b"\x61"
print(x)
b'a'
```

I really just want `\x61` to be shown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print a string as hexadecimal bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214801/print-a-string-as-hexadecimal-bytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [`binascii.hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) if you are happy with just hex digits (no `\x`)

```
import binascii
x = b"\x61"
print(binascii.hexlify(x))
```

output

```
b'61'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `int.from_bytes` to get the *integer represented by the given array of bytes*. This integer can then passed into the `hex` function to get the hex value.

```
>>> import sys
>>>
>>> x = b"\x61"
>>> hex(int.from_bytes(x, sys.byteorder))
'0x61'
```